# Is there a name/notation for the sum of the powers in a prime factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, prime-factorization

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, where $p_i$'s are distinct primes and $\alpha_i \geq 1$ for all $i$.

Is there any name & notation for the number $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2+ \cdots + \alpha_k$?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific name. What about "total prime multiplicity", "prime multiplicity" or just "multiplicity" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is $\Omega(n)$, that is number of prime divisors of $n$ counted with multiplicity.

See the OEIS sequence [A001222](https://oeis.org/A001222) for references. I would like to mention the paper:

[Robert E. Dressler and Jan van de Lune,  "Some remarks concerning the number theoretic functions $\omega(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$", Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 41 (1973), 403-406](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-041-02/S0002-9939-1973-0340191-8/home.html)

Answer (score 7):

Usually 
$\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of n,
and
$\Omega(n)$ denotes the number of prime factors counting multiplicity, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I think number of _distinct_ prime factors _counting multiplicity_ is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Indeed it seems the usual terminology is something like "number of prime factors counting multiplicity," without the word _distinct._

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\alpha_{1} + \dots + \alpha_{n}$ is the sum of the p-adic orders of the prime factors. Take a closer look [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity))